# C# Suppress all occurrences of same messages

Tags: .net

I'm trying to suppress this message (CA1053), I don't want it ever again to be displayed, but when I set to suppress it on Suppression file it is only for the case I selected with mouse cursor.

Any way to make it for all occurrences?

```
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Design", "CA1053:StaticHolderTypesShouldNotHaveConstructors", Scope = "type", Target = "Namespace.Class+Variable")]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to suppress this warning? The folks in Redmond explicitly say "do not suppress a warning from this rule".

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182169.aspx

Regardless, there is a box in the project properties that can help. Use at your own risk haha

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach to suppressing warnings would be to create a custom ruleset and simply exclude this rule from the your custom ruleset.
Every *.ruleset is really an xml file, so you can easily edit it, and keep in source control to share with your team and CI server
[image]